# JavaScript add hidden data to Object

Tags: javascript, object

Say I have an object like:

```js
const myObj = { color: 'red', score: 8 };
```

I can access these attributes with:

```js
myObj.color // 'red'
```

and:

```js
Object.values(myObj) // ['red', 8]
```

I want to be able to store extra data in the object, that is accessible, but won't be found by `Object.values()` for example:

```js
myObj.greeting // "hello"
// or alternatively
myObj.greeting() // "hello"
Object.values(myObj // ['red', 8] greeting is not picked up by Object.values()
```

Preferably using modern JavaScript like classes if necessary, rather than directly using prototypes.

Comment: Interestingly, when you use [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) as keys, they won't show in `Object.values()`: https://curiosity-driven.org/private-properties-in-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Object.defineProperty` that set `enumerable: false` (by default) so it is not shown/enumerated in the properties:

```js
const myObj = { color: 'red', score: 8 };
Object.defineProperty(myObj, "greeting", {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: "hello"
});
console.log(myObj.greeting);
console.log(myObj);
console.log(Object.values(myObj));
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

> This method allows a precise addition to or modification of a property on an object. Normal property addition through assignment creates properties which show up during property enumeration (for...in loop or Object.keys method), whose values may be changed, and which may be deleted. This method allows these extra details to be changed from their defaults. By default, values added using Object.defineProperty() are immutable and not enumerable.

Comment: enumerable is always `Defaults to false.` in `defineProperty` - **what are you suggesting here ?** Even if it `not` set to `false` - it will be `false` and results will be same

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes I know, but the goal was to highlight the property that solves the issue. Thank you for sharing. I updated the answer with more details.